# How to Get Local IP by SocketHandle?

Tags: delphi, client-server, handle

I am developing chatroom application - use TServerSocket and TClientSocket to Send and Receive Text
I Can get Socket.SocketHandle from computer that sent for me, but how to get local IP (or Computernetname) of that computer.

Comment: I thought `ScktComp` was depreciated and unrecommended?

Comment: @JerryDodge: It is deprecated, and has been for awhile now. But the OP did not specify which Delphi version he's using, so I'm guessing he's using an older version where those components had not been deprecated yet, especially considering that they have to be installed manually in modern Delphi versions in order to keep using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCustomWinSocket has `RemoteAddress` and `RemoteHost` properties to get the peer's IP and Hostname values, respectively.  You do not need to use the `SocketHandle` property unless you want to call Winsock API functions directly, like `getpeername()` and `getnameinfo()`.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!
I am only 15 years old and very like create some app by Delphi.
I Think i could study many things, Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code successfully for many years.  You must include `WinSock` in your `uses` list.  I have two global variables:

```
var
  FWSAData: TWSAData;
  FWSAStarted: Integer;
```

I use the following code to initialize the `WSA` one time, to avoid the overhead of doing it with each call to a WinSock method.

```
initialization
  FWSAStarted := WSAStartup(MakeLong(1, 1), FWSAData);

finalization
  if FWSAStarted = 0 then
    WSACleanup;
```

A user can have more than one local IP address.  The following code demonstrates how to get both the computer name (to get the IP address) and how to get all IP addresses, separated by semicolons using the WinSock API calls:

```
function _GetComputerName : string;
var
  len: DWORD;
begin
  len := MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
  SetLength (result, len);
  if not Windows.GetComputerName(PChar(result), len) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  SetLength(result, len);
end;

function GetIPAddress: AnsiString;
var
  Host: AnsiString;
  IPs, i: Integer;
  HostEnt: PHostEnt;
  b1, b2, b3, b4: Byte;
begin
  if FWSAStarted <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to hook WINSOCK.  "GetIPAddress" failed.');

  Result  := '';
  Host    := AnsiString(_GetComputerName);
  HostEnt := GetHostByName(PAnsiChar(Host));

  if Assigned(HostEnt) then
    with HostEnt^ do
      begin
        // the ip addresses occupy 4 bytes per address in sequence from the beginning
        // of the string, followed by the host name
        IPs := (Length(h_addr^) - Length(Host)) div 4;
        for i := 0 to IPs-1 do
        begin
          b1 := Byte(h_addr^[0+(4*i)]);
          b2 := Byte(h_addr^[1+(4*i)]);
          b3 := Byte(h_addr^[2+(4*i)]);
          b4 := Byte(h_addr^[3+(4*i)]);
          Result := Result + AnsiStrings.Format(';%u.%u.%u.%u', [b1, b2, b3, b4]);
        end;
        System.Delete(Result, 1, 1); // delete the first semicolon
      end;
end;
```

Comment: I may have misread your question. I thought you wanted to know how to get the IP address of the computer on which your app was running. It appears that you are asking how to get the local address of the remote computer. This code is only useful to get the local IP of the computer that is running your app.  If you are writing the apps for both the client and the server, then you can use this in the client app...

Comment: Thanks, but I think it long, just use RemoteAddress

Comment: @JamesL.: using `gethostbyname()` to retrieve local IPs is not 100% reliable as it does have some hidden gotchas in some configurations.  You really should be using `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()` instead, which are specifically designed for retrieving local adapter information, including IPs. Not to mention that `gethostbyname()` only supports IPv4, but `GetAdaptersAddresses()` supports both IPv4 and IPv6.